# debmirror not sync dist-upgrader-all correctly

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, local, mirror

We have mirrored the Ubuntu bionic from archive.ubuntu.com with debmirror tool in Centos 7 and we can upgrade servers with this local mirror without any issues,but when we were trying to do-release upgrade server we got error like below files are missing.

dists/bionic-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/ReleaseAnnouncement
dists/bionic-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/ReleaseAnnouncement.html
dists/bionic-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/bionic.tar.gz
dists/bionic-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/bionic.tar.gz.gpg

On checking the local mirror we found that folder dist-upgrader-all is not synced in local mirror. Further we tried to sync the folder main/dist-upgrader-all  with the below command(added main/dist-upgrader-all in section option)

debmirror -a amd64 --no-source -s main,main/dist-upgrader-all,restricted,universe -h archive.ubuntu.com  -d bionic,bionic-updates,bionic-security  -r /ubuntu  --progress  --method=rsync   --ignore-release-gpg   --no-check-gpg    /mnt/ubnutu_18

after the this command ran successfully, I can see the folder main/dist-upgrader-all has been created but the contents inside the folder main/dist-upgrader-all are

binary-amd64/
cnf/
dep11/
i18n/

but it should be

18.04.15/
18.04.16/
18.04.17/
current/

these are the contents available inside the dist-upgrader-all folder in http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/dist-upgrader-all I can see.

Not sure why debmirror sync different contents, this case is same for other release too bionic-updatebionic/main/dist-upgrader-all
bionic-security/main/dist-upgrader-all

Please let me know if you any idea about this, thanks in advance.

Comment: I am unsure why you want to mirror and loose a lot of space instead running apt-cacher-ng?

Comment: Yes it is better option, but we have this mirror setup already running in our repo server(Cenots) which is also a repository server for other Linux flavours, we can't switch to apt-cacher-ng soon.

Comment: do you develop packages?